# vagrant up after box shutdown

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

im having trouble with my vagrant and virtual box.
At first vagrant up and provision, the box is working. But after I tried to shutdown the box and run vagrant up again, this error has occured

```
johnmarlo@mac-mini:/var/www/project/loft/contents [master]$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["modifyvm", "593e3357-2f79-4d9a-9508-bec4c29cc9fb", "--natpf1", "delete", "ssh"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: Runtime error opening '/Users/johnmarlo/VirtualBox VMs/[PJT] Loft-VM/[PJT] Loft-VM.vbox-tmp' for reading: -102 (File not found.).
VBoxManage: error: /Users/vbox/tinderbox/4.2-mac-rel/src/VBox/Main/src-server/MachineImpl.cpp[9685] (nsresult Machine::saveSettings(bool*, int))
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component SessionMachine, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "SaveSettings()" at line 2527 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

Does any one encountered this? and how to fix this? Thanks for any of your reply m(_ _)m

Here is my Vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "debian-wheezy71-x64-vbox43"
    config.vm.box_url = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ffuenf-vagrant-boxes/debian/debian-7.1.0-amd64.box"
    config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.92.68"
    config.vm.hostname = "loft-vm"
    config.vm.synced_folder "server/", "/var/www/project/loft/contents/", owner: "vagrant", group: "vagrant"
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.name = "[PJT] Loft-VM"
        vb.gui = false
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512"]
    end

    config.vm.provision :shell, path: "cookbook/manifest/bootstrap.sh"
    config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
        puppet.module_path = "cookbook/modules"
        puppet.manifests_path = "cookbook/manifest"
        puppet.manifest_file = "core.pp"
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you supply your `vagrantfile`?

Comment: I updated my post m(_ _)m

Comment: the `vb.name` is being used as part of the path to the box.  will the brackets and space cause problems on a mac?  can you remove those?

Comment: :O wooah. so you mean that the `vb.name` is causing the problem? I didn't know that. (^^;) Thank you very much (y) I will just change it :) m(_ _)m

Comment: Post back if that solved the problem and I'll write it up as an answer so that it can help someone else.

Comment: Yes it works :) Thanks a lot (y) You saved my day :) m(_ _)m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `vb.name` (the Virtualbox name) is used to construct a path to the box.  The value of this string needs to be file-system friendly.  In your case, I believe the `[`s are causing problems.